Serializing OpenAPI objects created by swagger-parser to specification file
I'm trying to create a process that takes an OpenAPI specification file created by an external system, performs some modifications to make them work better as a Spring API, then writes the resulting file, which is then consumed by openapi-generator to create the API and Model classes.
I'm using swagger-parser to read the original file and I can make changes to the resulting OpenAPI objects. I've tried a couple of ways of serializing these objects to a JSON files, but openapi-generator runs into problems parsing these files.
Generally, the code looks like this:
SwaggerParseResult result = new OpenAPIParser().readLocation( INPUT_FILE, null, null );
OpenAPI openAPI = result.getOpenAPI();

// at this point, result.getMessages() is an empty list

/* ... tweak the API description ... */

String rawData = Json.pretty(openAPI);
try {
  FileUtils.writeStringToFile( OUTPUT_FILE, rawData, Charset.defaultCharset() );
} catch (IOException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException("Error writing file", e);
}

That Json.pretty is Swagger's own Json class for serializing an OpenAPI object.
The validation errors I'm seeing include:

Schemas end up with both a type property (a string) and types (an array of strings).
Extension fields (e.g., x-whatever) on objects are being rendered as fields within an extensions object.
A few extra internal fields on the OpenAPI objects end up in the JSON

As an example, this looks like:
  "components" : {
    "schemas" : {
      "something" : {
        "minLength" : 1,
        "maxLength" : 10,
        "type" : "string",
        "types" : [ "string" ],
        "extensions" : {
          "x-whatever" : true
        }
      }
...

I've tried constructing my own ObjectMapper with some custom mixins to hide/modify these problems, but it's becoming very complicated.
So how is one expected to serialize an OpenAPI object to a file in such a way that it can be parsed again by Swagger's own OpenAPIParser?

Is your OpenAPI spec 3.0 or 3.1?

The input spec and the resulting output spec are declared as 3.0.0. I've made sure that there's not a version mismatch between the version of swagger-parser that I'm using to manipulate the spec and the version used by openapi-generator.

Just to clarify, are you using Json.pretty() from the io.swagger.v3.core.util package? I've seen similar issues with extra fields and the extensions wrapper being added, from what I recall it was caused by ObjectMapper (mis)configuration but I don't remember the details. You'll probably have better luck asking about this issue in the swagger-parser repo: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser/issues

Found these similar old issues where the problem was caused by using a generic ObjectMapper instead of swagger-parser's ObjectMapper.

Yes, I was using the wrong version of Json! If you add this as an answer I will mark it as the solution!

Make sure you use Json.pretty() from the correct Swagger package:

OpenAPI 3.0.x → io.swagger.v3.core.util
OpenAPI 3.1 → Json31.pretty() from io.swagger.v3.core.util; see here about the differences in OAS 3.1 vs 3.0 (de)serialization
OpenAPI 2.0 → io.swagger.util

